# Hyper-V fails to start any virtual machine

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I just reinstalled the operating system, Windows 10, on my machine. Previously, I was able to use Hyper-V without problems, with the exact same OS image, but now it doesn't work.

I have created an empty virtual machine, just with a virtual disk, and the default options. When I try to start it, I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred while attempting to start the selected virtual machine(s).

'test' failed to start.
'test' could not initialize.
```

There are no details on what went wrong. I checked the logs with the following command:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName ="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V*"; StartTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10); }
```

But it does not provide any useful information:

```
   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
02/11/2017 14:25:13          15130 Error            'test' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 56728BA4-4F7C-4581-90DA-E1DC131DB2C4)
02/11/2017 14:25:13          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.
02/11/2017 14:25:13          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.
02/11/2017 14:25:13          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.
02/11/2017 14:25:13          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.
02/11/2017 14:25:13          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
02/11/2017 14:25:13           3040 Error            'test' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 56728BA4-4F7C-4581-90DA-E1DC131DB2C4)


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
02/11/2017 14:21:28          15130 Error            'test' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 56728BA4-4F7C-4581-90DA-E1DC131DB2C4)
02/11/2017 14:21:28          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.
02/11/2017 14:21:28          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.
02/11/2017 14:21:28          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.
02/11/2017 14:21:28          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.
02/11/2017 14:21:28          12514 Information      Found a certificate for server authentication. Remote access to virtual machines is now possible.


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
02/11/2017 14:21:28           3040 Error            'test' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 56728BA4-4F7C-4581-90DA-E1DC131DB2C4)


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
02/11/2017 14:21:21          27311 Information      The system successfully created 'D:\Hyper-V\test.vhdx'.
02/11/2017 14:21:20          27310 Information      The system is creating 'D:\Hyper-V\test.vhdx'.
02/11/2017 14:21:19          13002 Information      A new virtual machine 'test' was created. (Virtual machine ID 56728BA4-4F7C-4581-90DA-E1DC131DB2C4)
02/11/2017 14:21:19          18304 Information      The virtual machine 'test' was realized. (VMID 56728BA4-4F7C-4581-90DA-E1DC131DB2C4).
0
```

The BIOS settings have not changed since before reinstalling, so they should be correct. I have checked them and virtualization is enabled.

I have already tried uninstalling Hyper-V and reinstalling it, rebooted countless times, reset file system permissions, nothing helped.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You reset file permissions? On what exactly? Why would you randomly modify permissions?

Comment: Is the host domain joined, getting group policies? What generation are the vms? Did any TPM settings change?

Comment: Regarding file permissions, what I mean is that I changed the directory where the virtual machines and virtual disks are stored, and gave "everyone" full control.

Comment: @spacenomyous The host is domain joined, yes, and getting group policies. Before reinstalling, is was already joined to the same domain, but the group policies might have changed in the meantime, I don't know. Other people with the same OS image and joined to the same domain are able to use Hyper-V without issues. I tried both gen1 and gen2 VMS with the same results. I don't know how to check if TPM settings have changed.

Comment: Full control to Everyone? And you think it's enough? Won't you make some copies of your office's keys for the neighborhood?

Comment: @Marco That was the simplest way to test if that was a permission problem. Needless to say, I have already removed that permission.

Comment: I'm seeing based on some research `net localgroup administrators SERVICE /delete` doing the trick for whatever reason.

Comment: Yeah, i found that, but it did not work in my case... Thanks

Comment: Like the OP I have tried everything I found and nothing worked. I found this: "The problem you had seems to happen when Windows 10 is installed while virtualization is disabled in BIOS. Enabling virtualization afterwards causes Hyper-V to malfunction. Removing Hyper-V and reinstalling it will not fix it. Unfortunately, the only solution I know is to enable virtualization in BIOS before installing Windows 10. This seems to be a bug in Windows 10." Source: https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/machines-fail-to-start-and-initialize.68308/page-3

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the Hypervisor "forgot" to start automatically, you can try to use the following command in an elevated command prompt:

`BCDEDIT /Set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto`

Comment: I tried that but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a (Hyper V on Windows 10 Pro) VM was failing because there was no network adapters assigned to it. Once I assigned it one, the system started normally. If you are new to Hyper-V, follow these steps to configure it.

1. After powering down the VM, go to `Settings` (Not the Hyper-V settings). You can usually do that by right clicking on a VM in the `Virtual Machines` pane.
2. Select `Network Adapter`
3. On the details pane on top, in the `Virtual Switch` dropdown, select `Default Switch`.
4. Don't forget to click `Apply` to confirm your changes and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was found in [this post](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/379549-hyper-v-2012-vm-s-wont-initialize-no-other-error-msg?page=1):

The solution being running the following command:

```
net localgroup administrators SERVICE /delete
```

And then reboot afterwards.